# How to disable Device Location with Google APIs SettingsClient?

Tags: android, location, settings

In an effort to streamline UX, I want to change from: 
This:
 `startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));` 
which launches the system settings activity which enables user to turn on device 
location. 
To This:
 `LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);` 
which uses Google APIs [SettingsClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient) for a nicer dialog solution. 
This works nice to enable device location via built in, one touch dialog but does not seem to have a similar method for disabling device location.
Question: How to disable Device Location with Google APIs SettingsClient or another idea?